# explorer command not working in batch file

Tags: list, batch-file, for-loop

i have a batch file that opens an item in a list of paths but the  explorer command is not working (final is a list of paths )
can anyone tellme why this command isnt working

its sending the message:'explorer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set path=c:\users\user1\desktop
set numz=0 
set /p go=
for %%k in (%final%) do (
set /a "numz=!numz!+1"
if [!numz!]==[%go%] (explorer %%k)
)
```

Comment: as an alternative, you can use `start %%k` or more generic `start "" "%%~k%`

Comment: did you try calling explorer using the full path? ("C:\Windows\explorer.exe")

Comment: *Let me foolishly remove the known path to all applications by changing the PATH to point to only my desktop. Wait... Why don't programs outside my desktop folder run now?* @Stephan: Yeah, caught it; that's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: oh didn't see he changes his PATH var, thats a dangerous thing to do....

Comment: @weberik so didn't I. To be honest, your comment stubbed me into it.

Comment: thanks it works now. now i know not to mess with the variable called path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you changed the `%path%` variable. Don't do that (use another variable name).  Windows uses the `%path%` variable to know where to find it's executables. Because you deleted that info, Windows is not able to find `explorer.exe` any more - hence the error message.

Gladly, this concerns only the current `cmd` session (and it's daughter-processes). Change the variable name, close the `cmd` window, open a new one and it should work fine.

Comment: are there any more names i shouldnt change?

Comment: Quite a lot of them. In a fresh `cmd` window enter `set` (without any parameters). As you haven't set any variables, it shows you all the system variables. (read them - some of them are really useful)

Comment: Additionally, type `set /?` into a command prompt window and check out the last page of the help message; there are some built-in variables listed which are not listed when typing plain `set`, but those should also not be set but read only...